# Improving my latex codes for matrices

Tags: matrices

i want to write my latex code as in the image inserted below. Please can someone help me to improve my code here to let them look like in the image.

```
\begin{multline*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 k_{A,t} \\  k_{BC,t} \\  k_{M,t}  \\   k_{NB,t} \\   k_{NS,t} \\   k_{O,t}  \\  k_{PEI,t}\\  k_{Q,t}\\   k_{S,t}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
.43&-.03 & .03 & .09 & .03 & .06 & .30&-.11&-.10&-.22\\ 
.0008 & .57 & .12& .19& .08 & .50 &.0035 & -.25 & -.40\\
041 & .15 & -.11 & .30 & .10  & .22& .01 & -.07 & .02\\
.048 &  .10 &.03 & .28  &  .28  &  -.09 & .10 & .17 & -.13\\
.34 &   -.04 & .26&  .05& -.54 & .26 & 0.23 & .10 & .10 \\
.14 &   .20 & -.12 &  -.06 & .01 & .86 & .08 & -.001 & -.17 \\
.038 & -.07 &.07 &  .23 & -.08 & .31& .15 & .32 &-.32\\
.20 & .09 & .12 &-.05 & .04 & .10& .09 & .14 & .701&-.03\\
.14 & .06 & .17 & .32 &  0.25 & 0.12 & -.06 & - .12&-.04\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 k_{A,t-1} \\   k_{BC,t-1} \\  k_{M,t-1} \\    k_{NB,t-1} \\    k_{NS,t-1} \\     k_{O,t-1} \\    k_{PEI,t-1} \\  k_{Q,t-1} \\  k_{S,t-1}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \\
\begin{bmatrix}
-.26 & -.227 & -.26 &-.23 &.13 &-.05&0.34&-0.05 & -.18 \\ 
%.04 & -.25 & .08 & .20 & .03 & .30 & -.12 & -.09 & -.29\\ 
%.26 & .27 & -1.38 & .44 & -.02 & .12 & .01 & -.06 & .23\\ 
%.46 & .18 & -.23 & -.41 & .14 & -.13 & -.13 & -.01 & -.12\\ 
%.25 & -.19 & -.32 & .44 & -.35 &.52 &.24 &-.19 &-.33\\ 
%.19 & .16 & -.24 & .02 & -.01 & .01 & .03 & -.04 & -.16\\ 
%-.19 & .06 & -.03 & .09 & .24 & -.58 & .36 & -.48 & .002\\ 
%.29 & .04 & -.18 & .13 & .07 & .20& .15 & -.32 & .31\\ 
%.23 & .04 & -.9 & .40 & -.05 & .17 & -.07 & .17 & -.72\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
 11.74  \\ 8.59 \\ 10.93 \\  9.46 \\  -8.55 \\  .096 \\ -12.76 \\ -0.37\\  7.91\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multline*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok @cfr i will propose it better the next time.

Answer (score 2):

I use `TexStudio` version `2.8.0` (download [here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/)). It has specialized tools to format code of tables and matrices as shown in Figure (you can use other functions like *add* or *delete* *rows* (or *columns*))

[image]

The button [image] arranges the columns by placing the cursor within the respective `matrix` or `tabular` environment and clicking. If for some reason as to edit the code the alignment breaks it, repeat the process (click on button). This makes the code more readable.

If you don't want to add missing zeros before of decimal point (you could do this with *search* and *replacement* functions of `TexStudio`), you could try the package `siunitx` and its macro `\num{...}` and/or its *column specifier* `S` (for  `array` and `tabular`). This macro aligns columns by decimal point and adds zeros like in `.098` i.e `\num{.098}` `->` `0.098`. For more information read the [siunitx manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).

In my code I used the font package `stix` for being the most similar to the image and it fits perfectly in portrait mode (without landscape).

Here my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\noindent I want to write my latex code as in the image inserted below. Please can someone help me to improve my code here to let them look like in the image.
\begin{align*}
I=\begin{bmatrix}
    k_{1,t} \\
    k_{2,t} \\
    k_{3,t} \\
    k_{4,t} \\
    k_{5,t} \\
    k_{6,t} \\
    k_{7,t} \\
    k_{8,t} \\
    k_{9,t}
\end{bmatrix}
=&
\begin{bmatrix}
    11.74  \\
    8.59   \\
    10.93  \\
    9.46   \\
    -8.55  \\
    0.096  \\
    -12.76 \\
    -0.37  \\
    7.91
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.43   & -0.03 & 0.09  & 0.03  & 0.069 & 0.30  & -0.11 & 0.10   & -0.22 \\
    0.0008 & 0.57  & 0.12  & 0.19  & 0.08  & 0.50  & 0.035 & -0.25  & -0.40 \\
    0.041  & 0.15  & -0.11 & 0.30  & 0.10  & 0.22  & 0.01  & -0.07  & 0.02  \\
    0.048  & 0.10  & 0.03  & 0.28  & 0.28  & -0.09 & 0.10  & 0.17   & -0.13 \\
    0.34   & -0.04 & 0.26  & 0.05  & 0.54  & 0.26  & 0.23  & 0.10   & -0.10 \\
    0.14   & 0.20  & -0.12 & -0.06 & 0.01  & 0.86  & 0.08  & -0.001 & -0.17 \\
    0.038  & -0.07 & 0.07  & 0.23  & -0.08 & 0.31  & 0.15  & 0.32   & -0.32 \\
    0.20   & 0.09  & -0.05 & 0.04  & 0.10  & 0.09  & 0.14  & 0.70   & -0.3  \\
    0.14   & 0.06  & 0.17  & 0.32  & 0.25  & 0.12  & -0.06 & -0.12  & -0.04
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    k_{1,t-1} \\
    k_{2,t-1} \\
    k_{3,t-1} \\
    k_{4,t-1} \\
    k_{5,t-1} \\
    k_{6,t-1} \\
    k_{7,t-1} \\
    k_{8,t-1} \\
    k_{9,t-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\quad + \lambda 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -0.26 \\
    -0.22 \\
    -0.26 \\
    -0.23 \\
    0.13  \\
    -0.05 \\
    0.34  \\
    -0.05 \\
    -0.18
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: What package does the trick of aligning the rows? It is a problem that puzzles me often! Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean align the columns? there are several packages depending of the alignment you want. `array` package allows column specifiers `lcr`, `dcolumn` supports alignment by the decimal point, etc ...

Comment: Not really, I mean row alignment. In the question the metrices have different heights but in your answer, all of them have the same height. How did you achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Left aligned the k vectors.  Note the use of \arraystretch and \arraycolsep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% show text area

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}% default is 6pt
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
 k_{A,t} \\  k_{BC,t} \\  k_{M,t}  \\   k_{NB,t} \\   k_{NS,t} \\   k_{O,t}  \\  k_{PEI,t}\\  k_{Q,t}\\   k_{S,t}
\end{array}\right]
=&
\def\arraystretch{.9}
\begin{bmatrix}
 11.74  \\ 8.59 \\ 10.93 \\  9.46 \\  -8.55 \\  .096 \\ -12.76 \\ -0.37\\  7.91\\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
.43&-.03 & .09 & .03 & .06 & .30&-.11&-.10&-.22\\ 
.0008 & .57 & .12& .19& .08 & .50 &.0035 & -.25 & -.40\\
041 & .15 & -.11 & .30 & .10  & .22& .01 & -.07 & .02\\
.048 &  .10 &.03 & .28  &  .28  &  -.09 & .10 & .17 & -.13\\
.34 &   -.04 & .26&  .05& -.54 & .26 & 0.23 & .10 & .10 \\
.14 &   .20 & -.12 &  -.06 & .01 & .86 & .08 & -.001 & -.17 \\
.038 & -.07 &.07 &  .23 & -.08 & .31& .15 & .32 &-.32\\
.20 & .09 &-.05 & .04 & .10& .09 & .14 & .701&-.03\\
.14 & .06 & .17 & .32 &  0.25 & 0.12 & -.06 & - .12&-.04\\
\end{bmatrix}
\def\arraystretch{1.0}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
 k_{A,t-1} \\   k_{BC,t-1} \\  k_{M,t-1} \\    k_{NB,t-1} \\    k_{NS,t-1} \\     k_{O,t-1} \\    k_{PEI,t-1} \\  k_{Q,t-1} \\  k_{S,t-1}
\end{array}\right]
\\
&\quad + \lambda 
\def\arraystretch{.9}
\begin{bmatrix}
-.26 \\ -.227 \\ -.26 \\-.23 \\.13 \\-.05\\0.34\\-0.05 \\ -.18 \\ 
%.04 & -.25 & .08 & .20 & .03 & .30 & -.12 & -.09 & -.29\\ 
%.26 & .27 & -1.38 & .44 & -.02 & .12 & .01 & -.06 & .23\\ 
%.46 & .18 & -.23 & -.41 & .14 & -.13 & -.13 & -.01 & -.12\\ 
%.25 & -.19 & -.32 & .44 & -.35 &.52 &.24 &-.19 &-.33\\ 
%.19 & .16 & -.24 & .02 & -.01 & .01 & .03 & -.04 & -.16\\ 
%-.19 & .06 & -.03 & .09 & .24 & -.58 & .36 & -.48 & .002\\ 
%.29 & .04 & -.18 & .13 & .07 & .20& .15 & -.32 & .31\\ 
%.23 & .04 & -.9 & .40 & -.05 & .17 & -.07 & .17 & -.72\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: matrix eauation]

Comment: Can you find the same font used in the original question image?

Comment: Try \small, then try \footnotesize, then try \scriptsize...

Comment: @skpblack: The font looks like Times New Roman. Try adding `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to the preamble...

Comment: @Werner I do not refer the size but the shape, i tried `mathptmx` but it doesn't seem. Compare `\lambda` and the `2, 6, 3, 4, ...` numbers, they are very differents.

Comment: Go to http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html and pick one.