# get matrix aligned

Tags: align

How can I make the third matrix beginning from the second line?
And how to adjust the spacing of the second matrix since there are some items overlap together?

Thank you very much!
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
F=
    \begin{bmatrix} 
      F_ {11} & F_ {12} & 0\\
      F_ {21} & F_ {22} &0 \\
      0 & 0 & F_{33} 
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
    \begin{bmatrix} 
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}& 0\\
       \dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}  &0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} 
   \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix} 
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1} & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 2}& 0\\
       \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 1} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 2}  &0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1} 
   \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: For spacing, one typically adjusts \arraycolsep and \arraystretch.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192593/improving-my-latex-codes-for-matrices/192605#192605 for example.

Answer (score 7):

With an `align*` environment instead of `\[`...`\]`.

The spacing can be increased substituting `\\` with `\\[<space>]` as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
F&=
    \begin{bmatrix}
      F_ {11} & F_ {12} & 0\\[1ex]
      F_ {21} & F_ {22} &0 \\[1ex]
      0 & 0 & F_{33}
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}& 0\\[2ex]
       \dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}  &0 \\[2ex]
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}
   \end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
    & =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1} & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 2}& 0\\[2ex]
       \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 1} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 2}  &0 \\[2ex]
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1}
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a numbered equation, it is better to use a `split` inside an `equation` environment.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F&=
    \begin{bmatrix}
      F_ {11} & F_ {12} & 0\\[1ex]
      F_ {21} & F_ {22} &0 \\[1ex]
      0 & 0 & F_{33}
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}& 0\\[2ex]
       \dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}  &0 \\[2ex]
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}
   \end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
    & =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1} & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 2}& 0\\[2ex]
       \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 1} & 1+\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial 2}  &0 \\[2ex]
      0 & 0 & 1+ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial 1}
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Windy You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: I'd prefer `split` in this particular case, so passing to a numbered equation is easier.

Comment: @egreg You're right, of course.